# Stripe payment - Why when I call if payment_form.is_valid(): is it always invalid?

Tags: django, forms, stripe-payments

I am trying to take a Stripe payment but every time the function is_valid() returns false and the message "We were unable to take a payment with that card!" is displayed.

The payment is for a set amount of 5 Euros. I am using the credit card number 4242 4242 4242 4242 to test the payment.

The terminal states that the 'stripe_id' is required but I am at a loss as to what to do about that.

Can anyone help me find what is wrong with my code?

checkout.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}

{% block head_js %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="">
    //<![CDATA[
    Stripe.publishableKey = '{{ publishable }}';
   // ]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/stripe.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form action="{% url 'checkout' %}" method="post" id="payment-form" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <legend>Payment Details</legend>

    <div id="credit-card-errors" style="display: none;">
        <div class="alert-message block-message error" id="stripe-error-message"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        {{ payment_form|as_bootstrap }}
    </div>

    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <input class=" btn btn-primary" id="submit_payment_btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit Payment of 5 Euros">
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class MakePaymentForm(forms.Form):
    print("MakePaymentForm...")
    MONTH_CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(1, 12)]
    YEAR_CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(2019, 2040)]
    
    credit_card_number = forms.CharField(label='Credit Card Number', required=False)
    cvv = forms.CharField(label ='Security Code (CVV)', required=False)
    expiry_month = forms.ChoiceField(label="Month",choices=MONTH_CHOICES, required=False)
    expiry_year = forms.ChoiceField(label='year',choices=YEAR_CHOICES, required=False)
    stripe_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,  required=False)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import MakePaymentForm
from tickets.forms import TicketsForm
from tickets.models import Ticket
from django.conf import settings
from accounts.views import login, index 
from django.utils import timezone
import stripe
# Create your views here.

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET

@login_required()
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        payment_form = MakePaymentForm(request.POST)
        print("checkout...")

        if  payment_form.is_valid():
            print("Payment form is valid...")
            try:
                print("Just about to charge the customer...")
                customer = stripe.Charge.create(
                    amount=500,
                    currency="EUR",
                    description="Thank you for your contribution, it will really help our site" and request.user.email,
                    card=payment_form.cleaned_data['stripe_id']
                )
            except stripe.error.CardError:
                messages.error(request, "Your card was declined!")
            
            if customer.paid:
                print("Customer has paid...")
                messages.error(request, "You have successfully paid")
                return redirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Unable to take payment")
                return redirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            print("There are errors...")
            print(payment_form.errors)
            messages.error(request, "We were unable to take a payment with that card!")
    else:
        print("Method isn't post...")
        payment_form = MakePaymentForm()

    return render(request, "checkout.html", {"payment_form": payment_form, "publishable": settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE})
```

Here is the output in the terminal:

```
[14/Dec/2020 22:47:40] "GET /checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5688
checkout...
There are errors...
<ul class="errorlist"><li>stripe_id<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
[14/Dec/2020 22:47:51] "POST /checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5850
```

and here is stipe.js:

```
$(function(){
    $("#payment-form").submit(function() {
        console.log("#payment-form");
        var form = this;
        var card = {
            number: $("#id_credit_card_number").val(),
            expMonth: $("#id_expiry_month").val(),
            expYear: $("#id_expiry_year").val(),
            cvc: $("#id_cvv").val()
        };
    
    Stripe.createToken(card, function(status, response) {
        console.log("#createToken");
        if (status === 200) {
            $("#credit-card-errors").hide();
            $("#id_stripe_id").val(response.id);

            // Prevent the credit card details from being submitted
            // to our server
            $("#id_credit_card_number").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_cvv").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_expiry_month").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_expiry_year").removeAttr('name');

            form.submit();
        } else {
            $("#stripe-error-message").text(response.error.message);
            $("#credit-card-errors").show();
            $("#validate_card_btn").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

I have made and my form is now valid, but when it sends the payment request to Stripe I get the following error and it looks like stripe_id is blank. Any ideas?

[InvalidRequestError at /checkout/1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUJGs.png)

[InvalidRequestError at /checkout/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6rCd.png)

Comment: Can you please show the value which is printed on terminal for this line `print(payment_form.errors)` in `else` part of `form.isvalid()`, and also include relevant part of  `stripe.js` file

Comment: I have updated my post with the value in the terminal and strip.js :)

Comment: I have double checked my stripe_id in "env.py" and it is correct as far as I can see.

Comment: Firstly, you need to add a hidden field in your HTML `<input type="hidden" id="id_stripe_id" name='stripe_id'>` inside `form`.

Comment: Secondly, you must also include another element which is mentioned in your jquery function but present in your HTM eg: `#stripe-error-message`, `#credit-card-errors`, `#validate_card_btn`.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @MdZafarHassan. I have changed the HTML and I still get the same error message in the terminal. I have updated my code for the HTML above to show what I have changed. I am not entirely sure what you mean by the second part of your reply. Do you mean it is not present in my HTML and if so how what should it look like?

Comment: The problem must be with jquery then, maybe it must not be loading correctly, try to add an `alert` message at the beginning of your `stipe.js`, if this working correctly then try print `request.POST` inside `if request.method == "POST":` of your views.py file and check it should look somewhat like `<QueryDict: {'stripe_id': ['tok_1HvMp4K0COGGtjDyZ6llq3uX'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['ia5EcM0bthkJREY411n8DaGkk0s3N8o3sI68iN2721xLkLlKTCxb8Z4ustpBdNS']}>`.
AND also please remove the hidden field for tripe_id which I previously asked you to add.

Comment: I have put alert messages in stripe.js and it doesn't seem to be called at all. That may be the problem then!

Comment: I have been looking at this for the last few days but I still cannot see what the problem is. I have amended some of the code and updated the first post but nothing I do seems to help. I still get a problem with 'stripe_id'.Can anyone help?

Comment: @MdZafarHassan Thanks for your help last week. I have made progress and my form seems to be valid but when I submit my payment to Stripe I get an Invalid Request Error as shown in the screen prints that I have uploaded to the first post. It seems that stripe_id is blank but I am not sure if this is the problem. Any ideas anyone?